# How to define nullable response attributes?

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I'm using the Python library [`connexion`](http://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in conjunction with my Swagger specification which features the `x-nullable` attribute in some of the `definitions`.

This `x-nullable` attribute is essentially a polyfill for the lack of support for nullable attributes in [OAS 2.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md). However, most frameworks support it with varying degrees.

`connexion` does appear to support this attribute in parameters [but not responses](https://github.com/zalando/connexion/issues/226).

So if you attempt to return a response with `null` as a value for any of items return in a response with `x-nullable` and `validate_responses` set to `True` it will fail validation and produce `Response body does not conform to specification` in the response.

How best can I polyfill support for `x-nullable` in a `connexion` based Python application such as the ones generate from the [`swagger-codegen`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) tool?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to specify a [custom validator](http://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/response.html#custom-validator) that patches the JSON schema's in the definition of the `operation` passed to it.

```
from connexion.decorators.response import ResponseValidator

class CustomResponseValidator(ResponseValidator):
    def __init__(self, operation,  mimetype):
        operation.definitions = { name: self.patch_nullable_in_definition(definition) for name, definition in operation.definitions.items() }
        ResponseValidator.__init__(self, operation, mimetype)

    def patch_nullable_in_definition(self, definition):
        definition['properties'] = { key: property_ if '$ref' in property_ else self.patch_nullable_in_property(property_) for key, property_ in definition['properties'].items() }
        return definition

    def patch_nullable_in_property(self, property_):
        if isinstance(property_, dict) and \
           not isinstance(property_, list) and \
           'x-nullable' in property_ and \
           property_['x-nullable'] and \
           'type' in property_:
            if not isinstance(property_['type'], list):
                property_['type'] = [property_['type']]
            if not 'null' in property_['type']:
                property_['type'].append('null')
        return property_
```